# Does scarcity apply only to commodities?

Tags: macroeconomics

I feel like Wikipedia may be misleading me in a subtle or egregious way.

The very first line of [Scarcity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarcity) is:  "Scarcity is the limited availability of a commodity..."

It does, of course, helpfully provide that "a [commodity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodity) is an economic good or service that has full or substantial fungibility..."

My question, then, is:  Does it really make no sense in economics to discuss the scarcity of non-fungible goods?

(In the interest of full disclosure, my interest in the subject is mostly related to thinking around whether post-scarcity has anything at all to say about non-commodities, but that's quite a different set of questions.)

Comment: What is an example of a non-fungible good?

Comment: An original Picasso is an example of a non-fungible good.  It's certainly scarce in that there's a limited quantity -- namely, one.  It's not a commodity, for the same reason (there is no substitute for unique items.)

Comment: *Time* is always scarce, because it's always fleeting. IDK if that's typically considered a "commodity", but time is the ultimate scarcity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness, you might want to include the definition of [Fungibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) as well:  "In economics, fungibility is the property of a good or a commodity whose individual units are essentially interchangeable, and each of its parts is indistinguishable from another part."

If you have a collection of objects, and each object is (in some relevant sense) interchangeable with any of the other objects, then they are *fungible* and thus a *commodity*.  If there aren't very many of them, they may be *scarce*.

However, if you have a collection of objects, none of which are interchangeable with any others in a relevant sense, then they are essentially unique objects.  You could still say that they were *scarce* (there is only one of each) but not that they are *commodities*... though in practice, people typically don't refer to unique objects as *scarce*.